# Update fields in DB table by condition without loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to perform simple SQL UPDATE operator with EF Core and LINQ?
I want to use LINQ because of type and refactoring safety. And I need to avoid loading bulk of objects back and forth between an app and databse driver
Basically I need smth like this:

```
DB.Items.Update(i => i.Value = 5).Where(i => i.Flag > 5);
```

Comment: have a look at this library, it provides the way which you are looking to do : https://github.com/MercedeX/GenericDataManager i

Comment: As the name lets you allready assume LINQ is designed for *querying*, not for *updating*. So whatever you do with LINQ, it´ll **allways** return a new collection instead of updating an existing one.

Comment: Sure, I mean not LINQ itself but updating records in LINQ style. The GenericDataManager is a great library, but doesn't support EF Core(

Comment: Tracking issue on EF Repo https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/795

Answer (score 1):

You can use lightweight [EFBulk nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFBulk).

Example code:

```
var count = db.Items.Where(s => s.Title == "Game")
        .Update(o => new Item { Price = 999, Title = "Tablet" }, db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework works with models, so you cant directly update values on a linq query. what you can do, is use the [Attach()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) command, to create your models with the values you want to upadate, and save them to the DB

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to fetch all records to update.

Just create a queryable like this:

```
IQueryable<Item> items = DB.Items.Where(i => i.Flag > 5).Select(r => new Item
{
  .,
  .,
  .,
  Value = 5
});

DB.Items.UpdateRange(items);
```

Basically IQueryable is the in DB representation of a query.
It should update those items without fetching those.

Comment: This does fetch all items in the query. The query is executed by the `UpdateRange` method. Please test your code before posting. Also, it's not clear what `.,` means.